# Access 2010 - Select Distinct on two out of three columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

ACCESS 2010 - I have 3 columns in a table and would like to select records that are duplicated in column 1 (c1) but must be unique in column 2 (c2) and column 3 (c3)

```
Table1
   c1          c2          c3
1  bacct1      user1       log1
2  bacct1      user2       log2
3  bacct1      user3       log3
4  bacct2      user4       log4
5  bacct2      user4       log5
6  bacct3      user6       log6
7  bacct3      user7       log6
```

Ideal Results:

```
Query Results
   c1          c2          c3
1  bacct1      user1       log1
2  bacct1      user2       log2
3  bacct1      user3       log3
```

Records 4 through 7 should not be pulled and so far the only way I have been able to achieve my ideal results is to do a query(1) that first finds duplicates of c1 then groups those results in another query(2), then repeat query 1 and 2 several times till I have narrowed down my results but I am hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: *"Records 4 through 7 should not be pulled..."* Why? Because there are two rows with "user4" and two rows with "log6"?

Comment: For my purposes Records 1-3 are considered unique. Record 4 and 5 are considered the same record and Records 6 and 7 are considered the same as well.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you consider them the same record. Do you mind explaining why, though?

Comment: They are considered the same because of the relationship either c2 or c3 has with c1. Record 4 is the same as Record 5 because the combination of c1+c2 is the same for both even though c3 differs. Record 6 and 7 are the same because the combination of c1+c3 is the same for both even though c2 differs. Basically I have duplicated raw data that comes in daily and I need to see occurrences of Records 1-3. This may either clarify things or make them more complicated, sorry.

Comment: I edited my answer. The change might be closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables and data; you should do this part yourself.

```
create table table1 (
  id int primary key, 
  c1 char(6) not null, 
  c2 char(5) not null, 
  c3 char(4) not null
);

insert into table1 values
(1, 'bacct1', 'user1', 'log1'),
(2, 'bacct1', 'user2', 'log2'),
(3, 'bacct1', 'user3', 'log3'),
(4, 'bacct2', 'user4', 'log4'),
(5, 'bacct2', 'user4', 'log5'),
(6, 'bacct3', 'user6', 'log6'),
(7, 'bacct3', 'user7', 'log6');
```

It *sounds* like you're looking for something along these lines.

```
select t1.id, t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3
from table1 t1
inner join 
    (select c1, count(c1)
     from table1
     group by c1
     having count(c1) > 1) t2
on t1.c1 = t2.c1
inner join 
    (select c2, count(c2)
     from table1
     group by c2
     having count(c2) = 1) t3
on t1.c2 = t3.c2
inner join 
    (select c3, count(c3)
     from table1
     group by c3
     having count(c3) = 1) t4
on t1.c3 = t4.c3

ID   C1      C2     C3
--
1    bacct1  user1  log1
2    bacct1  user2  log2
3    bacct1  user3  log3
```

---

After reading your comments, this might be closer to what you need.  I wrote this in standard SQL. For Access, you'll need to remove comments and add parens for the inner SELECT statements.

```
select t1.id, t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3
from table1 t1
inner join 
    (-- Duplicated values in c1
     select c1, count(*)
     from table1
     group by c1
     having count(*) > 1 ) t2
on t1.c1 = t2.c1
inner join 
    (-- Unique combinations of c1 and c2
     select c1, c2, count(*)
     from table1
     group by c1, c2
     having count(c2) = 1 ) t3
on t1.c1 = t3.c1 and t1.c2 = t3.c2
inner join 
    (-- Unique combinations of c1 and c3
     select c1, c3, count(*)
     from table1
     group by c1, c3
     having count(*) = 1 ) t4
on t1.c1 = t4.c1 and t1.c3 = t4.c3
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also need a 3rd inner join to only get the values where `count(c1)>1`, since you're looking for duplicates in column `c1`?

Comment: @sigil: Yes, I would. Thanks for pointing that out. I read right past it.

Comment: This solution is definitely the direction I want to go and has for the most part provided the results I'm seeking. There are about 60 records that are currently not being pulled for whatever reason and I am going back through my data to figure out why. One thing to note for anyone planning on using this solution for Access 2010 is that multiple inner joins must be nested within parentheses.